# How to select only those elements with many children?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how can I select only the `div` that contains a specific number of `p` children, for example at least two?

```js
$(".myDiv").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
 <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
 <p class="my_p">1</p>
 <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
 <p class="my_p">1</p>
 <p class="my_p">2</p>
 <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selectors. Although use [direct child selector(`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to avoid nested children.

```js
$(".myDiv:has(>:nth-child(2))").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
  <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

---

Or use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method and filter based on children count.

```js
$(".myDiv").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length > 1;
}).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
  <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't easily check right now, but wouldn't that return elements with only one child which itself has two element children? And also those elements with two or more children (though admittedly that is allowed in the question, on second reading)?

Comment: @DavidThomas :  for avoiding that direct child selector can use `.myDiv:has(>:nth-child(2))`

Comment: I know, the comment was intended as a hint to edit your answer for the benefit of the OP and future visitors :)

Answer (score 1):

<del>Use the jQuery pseudo-selector `:gt`</del>

Sorry, I sux at jQuery, but here it is in JavaScript, using `nextElementSibling`. Basically it goes and finds all `<p>` then using `nextElementSibling` to single out the `<p>` that have at least one sibling. Flagging that group then references their parents by `parentNode` to finally highlight the parents.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var atLeast = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var qty = atLeast.length;
for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
  var p = atLeast[i];
  var sibs = p.nextElementSibling;
  if(sibs) {
    p.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
  <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: While the opposite of the request, can you explain how `:lt(2)` works please?  (I'm guessing it should `:ge(2)` to meet the question).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter ....... but this would select element up to an index..... read question carefully... ___only the div that contains a specific number of p children, for example at least two?___

Comment: Ok, changed to `:gt(0)`

Comment: :gt(0) highlight every divs except first.

Comment: Ok - so it's not looking at the child items at all.  It's just picking out the 2nd/3rd div which *coincidentally* have 2/3 children respectively.    That's not event remotely a solution.

Comment: Used JS instead, I know it's not tagged, but whatever.

Comment: Removed my -1.  *Working* alternatives, should always be appreciated even if they don't match the exact requirements because the next person with the same problem may prefer non-jquery approach.

Comment: Thanks, that next person is me, the more I learn plain JavaScript, the more I unlearn  jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JQuery as your per your question the way is to use `.length`, like this:

```
$(".parentSelector > p").length;
```

To be more precise:

```
var allListElements = $('div > p').parent();

$.each(allListElements, function(element) {
  console.log(this);

  if ( $( this ).children().length > 1) {
     $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
  }
});
```

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tQA8OwpA3a5mMPBO1VIe?p=preview).

Comment: Can you explain how this fits in the question?  It doesn't return that divs that have 2 or more children. (though can be adapted to)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```js
$('.myDiv').filter(function() {
   return $(this).children('p').length > 1;
}).css("background-color", "yellow")
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
  <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Child selectors. Also refer [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) link for more info

```js
$(".myDiv:has(>:nth-child(2))").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
  <p class="my_p">1</p>
  <p class="my_p">2</p>
  <p class="my_p">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution highlight every divs except first. If first div has multiple child the code doesn't work properly.